# Why does listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() return -1?

Tags: java, javafx

This had been causing me tons of errors at run-time for the past few days
- concurrent modification exception and null pointer exceptions

I don't remember what I added, but added a snippet of code in this segment and it threw a array out of bounds exception leading to me finding out it throws a negative index on top of the Null Pointer Exception it throws when nothing is in the viewList.

Why is this doing this? I just started fooling around with javafx this week and this leads me to believe that I must have messed up somewhere?

```
ObservableList<BusinessCard> observableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(); //initialized above

    // ListView Listener, changes text fields for the selected B.C in ViewList
    try {
        listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<BusinessCard>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends BusinessCard> arg0, BusinessCard oldval,BusinessCard newVal) {
                int index = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();

                if(index == -1) return;  //Fix          

                BusinessCard card = observableList.get(index);                      
                setDataFields(card);         
            }
        });
    } catch (NullPointerException e1) {
        // Do nothing, NullPointer thrown when list is empty
    }
```

Comment: what is `observableList` ? where is it defined ?

Comment: I guess your list model has option of deselection and for that event `BusinessCard newVal` is `null` and correspondingly `listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()`  is `-1`.

Comment: Why do you even get the `BusinessCard` from the list? Seems to me like `newVal` should already contain that value (or `null`), unless you're doing some really strange thing with your `ListView`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the [documentation for the selectedIndex property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SelectionModel.html#selectedIndexProperty) is pretty clear here.

> Refers to the selected index property, which is used to indicate the
>   currently selected index value in the selection model. The selected
>   index is either -1, to represent that there is no selection, or an
>   integer value that is within the range of the underlying data model
>   size.